# How to fix "Conversion from string "Num1" to type 'integer' is not valid" when the operation is double clicked in the listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am fairly new to VB.Net (still a student), bear with me.  When I double click on an operation (ex: `1 + 1 = 2`) in the listbox, I get a conversion error from string to type integer.
The access database (Calc -> My Calc table) I am saving/pulling from has the fields set to short text, so I don't understand how I am getting this error.  Everything else is working as I intended.

I have tried just about every conversion that I know on both the input and output ends.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class MainForm
    ' declare variables
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        ' declare variables
        Dim result As Decimal = 0
        Dim addMath As MathOp = New MathOp()

        ' load text entries into class
        addMath.decNum1 = CDec(txtNum1.Text)
        addMath.decNum2 = CDec(txtNum2.Text)

        ' calculate and display addition of the numbers
        result = addMath.addNum()
        addMath.decResult = result

        txtResult.Text = addMath.decNum1 & " + " & addMath.decNum2 & " = " & addMath.decResult
        Me.btnSave.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSub_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSub.Click

        ' declare variables
        Dim result As Decimal = 0
        Dim subMath As MathOp = New MathOp()

        ' load text entries into class
        subMath.decNum1 = CDec(txtNum1.Text)
        subMath.decNum2 = CDec(txtNum2.Text)

        ' calculate and display the subtraction of the numbers
        result = subMath.subNum()
        subMath.decResult = result
        txtResult.Text = subMath.decNum1 & " - " & subMath.decNum2 & " = " & subMath.decResult
        Me.btnSave.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMult_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMult.Click

        ' declare variables
        Dim result As Decimal = 0
        Dim multMath As MathOp2 = New MathOp2()

        ' load text entries into class
        multMath.decNum1 = CDec(txtNum1.Text)
        multMath.decNum2 = CDec(txtNum2.Text)

        ' calculate and display the multiplcation of the numbers
        result = multMath.multNum()
        multMath.decResult = result
        txtResult.Text = multMath.decNum1 & " x " & multMath.decNum2 & " = " & multMath.decResult
        Me.btnSave.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDiv_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDiv.Click

        ' declare variables
        Dim result As Decimal = 0
        Dim divMath As MathOp2 = New MathOp2()

        ' load text entries into cloass
        divMath.decNum1 = CDec(txtNum1.Text)
        divMath.decNum2 = CDec(txtNum2.Text)

        ' divides the 1st & 2nd number unless the 2nd number is a 0, then will display message box
        ' to user telling them they can't divide by 0
        Try
            result = divMath.divNum()
        Catch ex As DivideByZeroException When divMath.decNum2 = 0
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, You can't divide by 0.")
            txtNum2.Focus()
        End Try

        ' displays the results in the results text box, with only 2 decimal places, unless the 2nd number is a
        ' 0, then it will display the error in the results text box by utilizing a IF-THEN-ELSE statement
        If divMath.decNum2 = 0 Then
            txtResult.Text = "Can't divide by 0"
        Else
            divMath.decResult = result
            txtResult.Text = divMath.decNum1 & " / " & divMath.decNum2 & " = " & divMath.decResult.ToString("N2")
            Me.btnSave.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        Dim ask As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("This will clear all your records, would you like to continue?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo,
                                         "Clear History?")
        If ask = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
                con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\thiem\Desktop\Thieme_MyCalc 3\Thieme_MyCalc 3\Calc.mdb'"
                con.Open()

                Dim data As String = "DELETE * FROM MyCalc"
                Dim dataInsert As New OleDbCommand

                With dataInsert
                    .CommandText = data
                    .Connection = con
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
                con.Close()
            End Using

            ' clear all boxes
            lstOutput.DataSource = Nothing
            lstOutput.Items.Clear()
            txtNum1.Clear()
            txtNum2.Clear()
            txtResult.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        If (count < 10) Then
            Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
                con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\thiem\Desktop\Thieme_MyCalc 3\Thieme_MyCalc 3\Calc.mdb'"
                con.Open()

                Dim data As String = "INSERT INTO MyCalc (Num1, Num2, Result) VALUES (@Num1, @Num2, @Result);"

                Dim dataInsert As New OleDbCommand

                With dataInsert
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num1", txtNum1.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num2", txtNum2.Text)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtResult.Text)
                    .CommandText = data
                    .Connection = con
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With

                con.Close()

            End Using

            MessageBox.Show("Result Saved")
            count = count + 1
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you have exceeded 10 entries, press Clear.")
        End If
        Me.btnDisplay.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        ' declare variables
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection()
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\thiem\Desktop\Thieme_MyCalc 3\Thieme_MyCalc 3\Calc.mdb'"
        con.Open()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyCalc", con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        lstOutput.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        lstOutput.DisplayMember = "Result"

        Me.txtNum1.Focus()

    End Sub

    Private Sub lstOutput_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lstOutput.MouseDoubleClick

        Dim con As New OleDbConnection()
        Dim comm As New OleDbCommand()
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\thiem\Desktop\Thieme_MyCalc 3\Thieme_MyCalc 3\Calc.mdb'"

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim data As String = "SELECT * FROM MyCalc where Result = '" & lstOutput.Text & "'"

            comm = New OleDbCommand(data, con)
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read
                txtNum1.Text = reader.GetString(CInt("Num1")) 'CInt suggested by Visual Studio
                txtNum2.Text = reader.GetString(CInt("Num2")) 'CInt suggested by Visual Studio
                txtResult.Text = reader.GetString(CInt("Result")) 'CInt suggested by Visual Studio
            End While

            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Finally
            con.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub input_validation(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtNum1.KeyPress, txtNum2.KeyPress

        ' only allow numbers, decimal, and backspace in textboxes
        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "." AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txt_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNum1.Enter, txtNum2.Enter

        ' select all the text when entering a textbox
        txtNum1.SelectAll()
        txtNum2.SelectAll()

    End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
Public Class MathOp

    ' declare variables
    Public decNum1 As Decimal
    Public decNum2 As Decimal
    Public decResult As Decimal

    ' create function to add numbers
    Public Function addNum() As Decimal
        Return decNum1 + decNum2
    End Function

    ' create function to subtract numbers
    Public Function subNum() As Decimal
        Return decNum1 - decNum2
    End Function

End Class
```

---

```
Public Class MathOp2

    Inherits MathOp

    ' create function to multiply numbers
    Public Function multNum() As Decimal
        Return decNum1 * decNum2
    End Function

    ' create function to divide numbers
    Public Function divNum() As Decimal
        Return decNum1 / decNum2
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Hi and welcome,
you need to convert your input text to decimals like:  num = CDec(TextBox1.Text)

Comment: First thing you do (adopt it as it was a matter of life and death) is to set `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` `ON` by default in your Visual Studio configuration. -- As a note, try not to dump all of your code here, just the part that reproduces the *problem*.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the feedback, it is my first post here and I wasn't sure exactly where the problem lies.  I did implement the Option Strict and Option Explicit ON (This has been stressed in former classes, I just neglected to do it here) and it helped find a few things that needed to be fixed.

Comment: @minimalist Thanks as well for the response.  I implemented the conversion as you stated.  When I added Option Strict/Explicit ON, Visual Studio warned me of this error and your corrections helped.  However, after all the changes, I am still getting the conversion error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All, figured it out after doing further research and found a post from about 5 years ago (stackoverflow.com/questions/23042273/…). Basically, fixed it with this:

```
        While reader.Read
            txtNum1.Text = CType(reader("Num1"), String)
            txtNum2.Text = CType(reader("Num2"), String)
            txtResult.Text = CType(reader("Result"), String)
        End While
```

The post helped because it said to delete .GetString, then Visual Studio was able to suggest an edit to the code above... wanted to post it in case others are also having issues with the same thing.